# android -MutableLiveData doesn't observe on new data

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I'm using mvvm and android architecture component , i'm new in this architecture .

in my application , I get some data from web service and show them in recycleView , it works fine .

then I've a button for adding new data , when the user input the data , it goes into web service , then I have to get the data and update my adapter again.

this is my code in activity:

```
 private fun getUserCats() {
    vm.getCats().observe(this, Observer {
        if(it!=null) {
            rc_cats.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            pb.visibility=View.GONE
            catAdapter.reloadData(it)

        }
    })
}
```

this is view model :

```
class CategoryViewModel(private val model:CategoryModel): ViewModel() {

private lateinit var catsLiveData:MutableLiveData<MutableList<Cat>>

fun getCats():MutableLiveData<MutableList<Cat>>{
    if(!::catsLiveData.isInitialized){
        catsLiveData=model.getCats()
    }
    return catsLiveData;
}

fun addCat(catName:String){
    model.addCat(catName)
}

}
```

and this is my model class:

```
class CategoryModel(
    private val netManager: NetManager,
    private val sharedPrefManager: SharedPrefManager) {

private lateinit var categoryDao: CategoryDao
private lateinit var dbConnection: DbConnection
private lateinit var lastUpdate: LastUpdate

fun getCats(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<Cat>> {
    dbConnection = DbConnection.getInstance(MyApp.INSTANCE)!!
    categoryDao = dbConnection.CategoryDao()
    lastUpdate = LastUpdate(MyApp.INSTANCE)

    if (netManager.isConnected!!) {
        return getCatsOnline();
    } else {
        return getCatsOffline();
    }
}

fun addCat(catName: String) {
    val Category = ApiConnection.client.create(Category::class.java)
    Category.newCategory(catName, sharedPrefManager.getUid())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    { success ->
                        getCatsOnline()
                    }, { error ->
                Log.v("this", "ErrorNewCat " + error.localizedMessage)
            }
            )
}

private fun getCatsOnline(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<Cat>> {
    Log.v("this", "online ");
    var list: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Cat>> = MutableLiveData()
    list = getCatsOffline()

    val getCats = ApiConnection.client.create(Category::class.java)
    getCats.getCats(sharedPrefManager.getUid(), lastUpdate.getLastCatDate())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    { success ->
                        list += success.cats
                        lastUpdate.setLastCatDate()

                        Observable.just(DbConnection)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .subscribe({ db ->
                                    categoryDao.insert(success.cats)
                                })

                    }, { error ->
                Log.v("this", "ErrorGetCats " + error.localizedMessage);
            }
            )

    return list;
}
```

I call getCat from activity and it goes into model and send it to my web service , after it was successful I call getCatsOnline method to get the data again from webservice .

as I debugged , it gets the data but it doesn't notify my activity , I mean the observer is not triggered in my activity .

how can I fix this ? what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have made several different mistakes of varying importance in `LiveData` and `RxJava` usage, as well as MVVM design itself.

**LiveData and RxJava**

Note that `LiveData` and `RxJava` are streams. They are not one time use, so you need to observe the same `LiveData` object, and more importantly that same `LiveData` object needs to get updated.

If you look at `getCatsOnline()` method, every time the method gets called it's creating a whole new `LiveData` instance. That instance is different from the previous `LiveData` object, so whatever that is listening to the previous `LiveData` object won't get notified to the new change.

And few additional tips:

- In `getCatsOnline()` you are subscribing to an `Observable` inside of another subscriber. That is common mistake from beginners who treat `RxJava` as a call back. It is not a call back, and you need to chain these calls.
- Do not `subscribe` in *Model* layer, because it breaks the stream and you cannot tell when to unsubscribe.
- It does not make sense to ever use `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`. There is no need to switch to main thread in *Model* layer especially since `LiveData` observers only run on main thread.
- Do not expose `MutableLiveData` to other layer. Just return as `LiveData`.

One last thing I want to point out is that you are using `RxJava` and `LiveData` together. Since you are new to both, I recommend you to stick with just one of them. If you must need to use both, use [LiveDataReactiveStreams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams) to bridge these two correctly.

**Design**

How to fix all this? I am guessing that what you are trying to do is to:

(1) view needs category -> (2) get categories from the server -> (3) create/update an observable `list` object with the new cats, and independently keep the result in DB -> (4) `list` instance should notify activity automatically.

It is difficult to pull this off correctly because you have this `list` instance that you have to manually create and update. You also need to worry about where and how long to keep this `list` instance.

A better design would be:

(1) view needs category -> (2) get a `LiveData` from DB and observe -> (3) get new categories from the server and update DB with the server response -> (4) view is notified automatically because it's been observing DB!

This is much easier to implement because it has this one way dependency: View -> DB -> Server

Example CategoryModel:

```
class CategoryModel(
    private val netManager: NetManager,
    private val sharedPrefManager: SharedPrefManager) {

    private val categoryDao: CategoryDao
    private val dbConnection: DbConnection
    private var lastUpdate: LastUpdate // Maybe store this value in more persistent place..


    fun getInstance(netManager: NetManager, sharedPrefManager: SharedPrefManager) {
        // ... singleton
    }


    fun getCats(): Observable<List<Cat>> {
        return getCatsOffline();
    }

    // Notice this method returns just Completable. Any new data should be observed through `getCats()` method.
    fun refreshCats(): Completable {
        val getCats = ApiConnection.client.create(Category::class.java)

        // getCats method may return a Single
        return getCats.getCats(sharedPrefManager.getUid(), lastUpdate.getLastCatDate())
            .flatMap { success -> categoryDao.insert(success.cats) } // insert to db
            .doOnSuccess { lastUpdate.setLastCatDate() }
            .ignoreElement()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }


    fun addCat(catName: String): Completable {
         val Category = ApiConnection.client.create(Category::class.java)

         // newCategory may return a Single
         return Category.newCategory(catName, sharedPrefManager.getUid())
             .ignoreElement()
             .andThen(refreshCats())
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        )
    }
}
```

I recommend you to read through [Guide to App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) and one of these livedata-mvvm example [app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-live/) from Google.